# B43legacy drivers for broadcom wireless

Tags: wireless, broadcom

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get Broadcom BCM 43XX Wireless card working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-get-broadcom-bcm-43xx-wireless-card-working)

I have attempted the legacy drivers as my laptop I installed ubuntu on, is a old HP 4306 model of Broadcom.

However, after installing and rebooting a few times, I am still unable to see anything listed under addition drivers.

Any suggestions? Wireless isn't greyed out, it is checked off to use. But it doesn't light up on my laptop. There is an actual button I can turn on/off when in Windows environment.

Thanks for any help.